# Huggingface BERT SequenceClassification - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: pytorch, classification, bert-language-model

The class labels for the two class model is 0, 1, 0, 0, etc. There is only one
label per input sequence. The labels are set in a python list and converted to
torch.Tensor. (reading from a csv file - straight forward).

its value: tensor(0)
its shape is shown as: torch.Size([])

when i create the batch, etc. and set the parameters in the model (huggingface sequenceclassification model)

for each batch iteration,

```
   b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
   b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
   b_token_type_ids = batch[2].to(device)
   b_labels = batch[3].to(device)
```

and then set to the model (as part of training)

```
loss, logits = model(b_input_ids, 
                     attention_mask=b_input_mask, 
                     token_type_ids=b_token_type_ids,
                     labels=b_labels)
```

**The error message is as follows**:

```
    ValueError                                
    
        Traceback (most recent call last)
        
        <ipython-input-17-b3a36df2f659> in <module>()
             89                              attention_mask=b_input_mask,
             90                              token_type_ids=b_token_type_ids,
        ---> 91                              labels=b_labels)
             92 
             93         # Accumulate the training loss over all of the batches so that we can
        
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This was code I was able to use and train a few days ago. (I have a saved model).
The error message (I assume ) probably has something to do with the size etc.

Has anyone hit a similar problem? thanks.

Comment: Hugging face website has an additional unsqueeze on the labels (from  https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html#trainer )                                                           
    labels = torch.tensor([1,0]).unsqueeze(0)
outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)

Comment: please also show the model initialization code

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but it occurs when I use XLNet and BART, any idea how to resolve this?